# Attempted relative import with no known parent package error

Tags: python

```
Error: While importing "wsgi-contract-test", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karl/Development/tral/bin/tral-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 236, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/karl/Development/tral/test/contract/inject/wsgi-contract-test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import (
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

ERROR (run-tral): trap on error (rc=2) near line 121
make: *** [component.mk:114: tral-local-run-api-contract-test] Error 2
```

wsgi-contract-test.py:

```
from ...libs.tral import app, setup_from_env
from ...libs.tral import routes
```

I have the regular source files under the `libs/tral` directory, however the entry file for this test is located under `test/contract/inject`. I do NOT want to move this test file into libs since this file should be nowhere near production code as it is a rather hazardous file security wise.

In node.js this would of worked fine but there seems to be something with python imports I'm not grasping?

Comment: How are you running your tests? You can only use relative imports in python when under a tree of packages.  For tests we often do `sys.path` trickery in the test configuration to appear as though we at the usual entry point.  Whilst python has implicit (namespace) packages, you're better off IMHO with explicitly placing an `__init__.py` on package dirs. If you do that you'll likely see there is no sensible route between the tests dir and the code.  In which case you need either sys.path trickery, or run against an installed copy if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm needing to run the `test/contract/inject/wsgi-contract-test.py` file, that files imports things however from `libs/tral`.

Comment: Ah ok! I'll have a look at the `sys.path` magic^^

Comment: You might also want to run your tests with e.g. pytest (in which case you do the setup in contest.py)

Comment: For this specific type of test I need to run an actual instance of the application before triggering the tests (so it's a two step process)

Comment: @basickari running an instance of the application before testing is no problem for a test runner!  (And is quite a common paradigm in server/client testing).  See my answer (although you definitely can skip the runner and do everything yourself).

Answer (score 2):

Since tests don't belong inside the `src` tree, there are basically two approaches.  If you are testing a *library* you will frequently install it (in a virtualenv) and then just import it exactly the same way you would anywhere else.  Frequently you also do this with a fresh install for the test: this has the great advantage that your tests mirror real setups, and helps to catch bugs like forgetting to commit/include files (guilty!) and only noticing once you've deployed...

The other option is to modify `sys.path` so that your test is effectively in the same place as your production code:

```py
# /test/contract/inject.py
from pathlib import Path
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent))
```

Since `sys.path` uses strs you may prefer to use `os.path`, like every single other example on SO.  Personally I'm addicted to pathlib.  Here:

- `__file__` is the absolute path of the current file
- `Path(str)` wraps it in a `pathlib.Path` object
- `.parent` gets you up the tree, and
- `str()` casts back to the format sys.path expects, or it won't work.

### Using a test runner

Normally we use a test runner for tests.  But these tests need a running instance!  No problem:

```py
# tests/conftest.py
import pytest
from sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
# now pytest can find the src
from app import get_instance # dummy

@pytest.fixture
def instance():
    instance = get_instance(some_param)
    # maybe
    instance.do_some_setup()
    yield instance
    # maybe
    instance.do_some_cleanup()
```

If you don't need to do any cleanup, you can just `return` the instance rather than yielding it.  Then in another file (for neatness) you write tests like this:

```py
# tests/test_instance.py

def test_instance(instance): # note how we requested the fixture
    assert instance.some_method()
```

And you run your tests with pytest:

```sh
pytest tests/
```

Pytest will run the code in `conftest.py`, discover all test fns starting with `test` in files whose names start with `test`, run the tests (supplying all the *fixtures* you have defined) and report.

### Fixture Lifetime

Sometimes spinning up a fixture can be expensive.  See the docs on [fixture scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) for telling pytest to keep the fixture around and supply it to multiple tests.

### Using a runner vs. just running a script

You don't *have* to use a runner.  But they do have many advantages:

- decent metrics e.g. code/branch coverage
- everyone uses them
- parallel testing against different envs (e.g. python versions)
- tests tend to be a lot neater

Comment: Hey! I added the sys.path thing however I'm getting the following error now: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs'` when I do a `from libs.tral import routes`. Also if I try `from tral import routes` it throws the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tral'`

Comment: print your `sys.path[0]` and check it is actually set correctly. Your dirs were slightly ambigious and I was guessing.  If libs is a package (dir) then you want to inject the dir just above it (if it's a file you want to inject the dir containing it).  I.e. you may need fewer/more .parents.

Comment: `/Users/karl/Development/tral/` is the output, it's the parent of both the `libs` and the `test` directory so it should be right? The `libs` directory is just a directory and the `libs/tral` directory has a `__init__,py` file and all of the other files we use.

Comment: So you want to be inside the `libs` dir and do `from tral import...` (unless you want `libs` to be apackage, which is unlikely: in that case put  and `__init__.py` inside it.

Comment: Hey man I'm upvoting you even if the solution turned out different, thank you for your help you actually got me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

I took for granted that Python was able to handle simple relative paths; not the case. Instead I just added the path to the packages I wanted to include in the `PYTHONPATH` variable and voila, it found everything.

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$(pwd)/libs"
```

Then running it from the root project directory.

I had to change the code to the following though:

```
from tral import app, setup_from_env
from tral import routes
```

Comment: Setting pythonpath effectively modifies sys.path, in this case inserting the path to /lib.  The env var is a perfectly respectable way to do it which I admit I'd forgotten :D